# ITextSharp 4.1.6 extract PDF content as text

Tags: c#, .net-core, itext

The company would like to use the `Itextsharp 4.1.6` version specifically and don't want to buy the license (version 5/7). 
So, we had already implemented the TextExtract from pdf using the `itextsharp` 5 version. As we downgraded, this method doesn't support in the 4.16 LGPL version.

So, I looked into many StackOverflow and other sites for the answer. Looks like no custom implementation found other than the below code which exists in AGPL version.

`PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy())`

And `byte[] pageContent = reader.GetPageContent(i);` gives the byte content, when converted to string it won't give us the exact file text.

As, we do not wish to buy the AGPL version and need to implement the `textextractor` of pdf, any idea if any other tool supports this/ anybody has the implementation of `textextractor`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Refernce for the @jgoday's answer:
[image]

Comment: To truly develop something comparable to the itext 5.5.x state of text extraction will require some months of development, more if you're not knowledgeable in pdf internals yet. So why should anyone have invested that time to develop that on top of itextsharp 4.x if there already is the original in itextsharp 5.x?

Comment: That being said, a first proof of concept of the itext text extraction functionality has been developed before the switch to AGPL in the java variant of itext. You might test it, and if it suffices for your requirements, you can port it to c#. Beware, though, that version is fairly limited in comparison with the 5.5.x implementation. On the other hand it's much more advanced than the extractor in @jgoday's answer, though, so probably worth a try nonetheless.

Comment: @mkl: yes, absolutely right.. it was perfectly working fine with AGPL version but the problem is that we need to buy commercial license which we cannot. and yes, to implement extract from scratch needs a couple of months... is there any other tool/other free software which has this functionality... as all cannot proceed with AGPL right?

Comment: @mkl: okay do u help me to know the first POC extraction functionality? any hint of the dll/method which i can search for?

Comment: As said above, it's in the java version. Cf. The openpdf project.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Always post the actual code so it can be copy/pasted into an IDE.

Comment: @Lak if you cannot buy a commercal license, then maybe you can consider releasing your own software with the AGPL license (which means, among others, giving away your source code to your end users). If you do that, then you can use iText 5 and iText 7.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I think the main part of the screen shot is **not** the code but the inspection value in the popup, i.e. `q1001...DoQ`. But indeed, the OP should have posted that as text.

Comment: @mkl I get triggered every time I see a screenshot of source code and I stop looking at what is actually in the screenshot. Can't blame me for that, can you?

Comment: Taking your screen shot into account there appears to have been some XObject drawing instruction (`/mx5 Do`). If that is an image XObject, you'll need an OCR solution anyways. If that is a form XObject, I'll have to tell you that support for form XObjects is not in the proof-of-concept present in the Java iText before 5.0. Thus, that poc alone won't help you.

Comment: *"as all cannot proceed with AGPL right?"* - That is not completely right; you might have to change your business model, though: If you use the AGPL version, your program will become AGPL, too. Depending on your software, though, you might switch to earning money for consulting work for your program.

Comment: @Amedee Van Gasse:"giving away your source code to your end users" - yes even this is not agreed by the company..

Comment: @mkl: "If you use the AGPL version, your program will become AGPL, too. you might switch to earning money for consulting work for your program " - agreed.. but unfortunately not in our context. and i'm afraid can this be fixed, can i get the pdf content in a couple of days easily... tried pdfsharp as well... but no luck

Comment: I'm afraid that if you limit yourself to iText .NET 4.1.6 and no AGPL, that the chances for a solution may be non existent, for the technical reasons mkl has been so kind to point out. Please talk to your management. As you write yourself: _it was perfectly working fine with AGPL version_. You know, if people like you buy licenses, then people like me get paid a salary.

Comment: Lak, if you wonder why @Vive removed the pdfsharp tag... your question clearly is iTextSharp centered. To try with pdfsharp, create a new question in which you demonstrate how far your attempts to extract text with it got. I'm sure Vive will help you on from there.

Comment: Mkl: Thanks a lot for helping me analyzing the issue so far. Sure, will give a try on all..

Answer (score 3):

With iText 4.1 you can use PdfContentParser (https://github.com/schourode/iTextSharp-LGPL/blob/f75cdad88236d502af42458a420d48be2a47008f/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfContentParser.cs), to parse contents of every page.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace PdfExtractor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var reader = new PdfReader(@"D:\Tmp\sample.pdf");

            try
            {
                var parser = new PdfContentParser(new PRTokeniser(reader.GetPageContent(2)));

                var sb = new StringBuilder();

                while (parser.Tokeniser.NextToken())
                {
                    if (parser.Tokeniser.TokenType == PRTokeniser.TK_STRING)
                    {
                        string str = parser.Tokeniser.StringValue;
                        sb.Append(str);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            }
            finally {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.. i tried the above code.. "parser.Tokeniser.NextToken()" only once it will be true and "parser.Tokeniser.TokenType" coming as PRTokeniser.TK_NAME... so after one loop it exits...i think this is because of "reader.GetPageContent(2)" which reads as bytes from the stream

Comment: i just pasted the result i'm receiving on the pdf in the question, as i wasnt able to upload the image here...as parser.Tokeniser.TokenType changes each time i have put the different condition "!=".

Comment: @jgoday Your solution only returns acceptable results for very special PDFs. In particular, the font encodings involved must be **WinAnsiEncoding** (or very similar to that), the order of text drawing instructions must match the reading order of the drawn text, actual space characters must be drawn (instead of separating words by means of text position shifts), and all text must be in the page content streams directly, not in separate XObjects. Such PDFs exist but there are more PDFs in the wild which aren't of that type.

Comment: @Lak Your change in code causes the result not only contain the contents of string arguments of drawing instructions but instead all kinds of instructions and parameters. The result is not really helpful as you see in your screen shot...

Comment: @mkl this was not intended to be a complete solution, simply an example of how to access the text of different objects. Anyway, your point is totally ok.